# Cant get value from variable in tpl. MODX

Tags: modx

I am junior in modx. Please help. I can't get value in my tpl file. In template I use code for displaying data

```html
<div class="animation-line">
                        <h3 class="times_font other"><span>[[%popular-stat? namespace=`alma-mebel`]]</span></h3>
                        <div class="similar_items_block">
                            [[!getResources?
                                &parents=`[[%12:babelid]]`
                                &includeContent=`1`
                                &includeTVs=`1`
                                &limit=`4`
                                &sortbyTV=`HitsPage`
                                &tpl=`sidebar-item`
                            ]]
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

After that I trying to get value from variable "name" in my tpl file

```html
<p class="item_header times_font"><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[*name]]</a></p>
```

But after that from [[*name]] I get an empty value. This works in template, but in chank this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To include TVs in your getResources call, you need to do the following:

```
&includeTVs=`add,tv,names,here,comma,separated`
```

To output the value of **name** tv, you need to call it as a placeholder in your chunk:

```
[[+tv.name]]
```

Hope this helps.